# Recursion with Memoization on a Datastructure

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

I am trying to implement memoization on the following problem.
The data structure is as follows :

```
ROWS = {368: [247, 257], 257: [368], 2468: [357], 357: [2468], 358: [247], 247: [358, 368]}
```

It is a dictionary in which the keys have values as lists. In each list of every key the elements contain digits different from the key. Example : if we take the key 368 : [247, 257] we observe that 247 does not contain any digit from its key 368. The same is with 257 and 368, different digits.

The problem is as follows: Construct a wall of certain height with numbers on top of each other by using this data structure such that no neighbors have the same digits.
For example a wall of level 4 would be :

```
1. 368, 247, 358, 247
2. 368, 257, 368, 257 ... and so on.
```

Question is : How many possible combinations of height n (in our case 4), are there ?

I made basic recursive and very ineffective and non-elegant solution, when starting with a single element :

```
ROWS = {368: [247, 257], 257: [368], 2468: [357], 357: [2468], 358: [247], 
247: [358, 368]} 
SUM=0

def count_configurations( elem , rows ) :
   global SUM
   if rows == 1 :
      SUM += len(ROWS[elem])
      return len(ROWS[elem])
   else:
      for k in ROWS[elem] :
         count_configurations( k, rows-1 )
```

It works fine but when we go up to a bigger height without Memoization it stays forever. Also if a try to **return count_configurations( k, rows-1 )** it returns at the first element and exits giving an incorrect answer.
The problem is that when dealing with this problem we don't have returns as numbers like in Fibonacci, but we will have returns some other lists. Example :
For level 4 would be something like :

```
(368, 4) : [(247:3), (257:3)]   (composed of 2 elements of level 3, then 
(247:3) :  [(358:2), (368:2)]  and  (257:3) :[(368,2)] (composed of elements of level 2)
```

and so on until we end up at level 1 where we can replace with actual values :

```
(368,1)=2 , (247, 1) = 1 , etc ...
```

Can be Memoization be implemented in this case ? Have I used a wrong data structure and I over complicated things ? Can you give me some advice on how to simplify things ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Memoization appears to work fine here:

```
>>> from functools import lru_cache
>>>
>>> @lru_cache(None)
... def count_configurations( elem , rows ) :
...     if rows == 1 :
...         return len(ROWS[elem])
...     else:
...         return sum(count_configurations( k, rows-1 ) for k in ROWS[elem])
```

Examples:

```
>>> count_configurations(247, 30)
2178309
>>> count_configurations(368, 100)
927372692193078999176
>>> count_configurations(357, 100)
1
>>> count_configurations(257, 100)
573147844013817084101
```